# Plot Additional Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, plot

i have code that looks like this below and I"m trying to draw a black line on the plot shown for Jul - Dec for the data in the df "ltyc". My error is at the very end just before the plt.legend line.

```
import warnings
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'
from sys import exit

df = pd.read_excel("MOSDailyWindSpeed.xlsx")

wspdBH1 = df.groupby('Date')[' Simulated WS BH1PI'].sum().reset_index()
wspdHOO = df.groupby('Date')[' Simulated WS HOO801'].sum().reset_index()
wspdBH1 = wspdBH1.set_index('Date')
wspdHOO = wspdHOO.set_index('Date')
wspdBH1.index
wspdHOO.index
y = wspdHOO[' Simulated WS HOO801'].resample('MS').mean()#monthly mean --> 
change site here 'MS' is month start for 'Date' col
y['2017':]#look at daily data starting 2017 -view data 

y.plot(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.show()

from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 18, 8

decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, model='additive')
fig = decomposition.plot()
plt.show()

p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, 
d, q))]

print('Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...')
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[1]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[2]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[3]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[4]))

for param in pdq:
  for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
    try:
        mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                        order=param,
                                        seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                        enforce_stationarity=False,
                                        enforce_invertibility=False)

        results = mod.fit()

        print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, 
results.aic))
    except:
        continue

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                            order=(1, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])        

results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.show()

# VALIDATE THE FORECAST - PLOT FORECAST VS ACTUAL 
pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'), 
dynamic=False)
pred_ci = pred.conf_int()
ax = y['2019':].plot(label='observed')
pred.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='One-step ahead Forecast', alpha=.7, 
figsize=(14, 7))

ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.2)

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Furniture Sales')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

y_forecasted = pred.predicted_mean
y_truth = y['2019-01-01':]

# Compute the mean square error
mse = ((y_forecasted - y_truth) ** 2).mean()
print('The Mean Squared Error of our forecasts is {}'.format(round(mse, 
2)))
print('The Root Mean Squared Error of our forecasts is 
{}'.format(round(np.sqrt(mse), 2)))

#PRODUCE AND VISUALIZE FORECAST
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=6)
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()

ax = y['2019':].plot(label='observed', figsize=(14, 7))
pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('MOS Wind Speed')
#add the LT monthly average to plot
from datetime import date
cm = date.today().month
lty = y.groupby(y.index.month).mean()
lty = lty.to_frame()
ltyc = lty.iloc[cm-1:12].reset_index() # extract curr month to end of LT 
mean monthly wind speed
ltyc.plot(label='LT Mean',ax=ax, color='k')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The ltyc df looks like this that I am trying to plot in the image below using axis = ax. I think I need to change the "Date" col below since the current axis doesn't interpret 7,8,9,10,11,12 as months but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
   Date   Simulated WS HOO801
0     7              5.491916
1     8              5.596823
2     9              5.793934
3    10              7.501096
4    11              8.152358
5    12              8.426322
```

Finally, my error looks like this:

```
File 
"C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\timeseries.py", line 309, in 
format_dateaxis
raise TypeError("index type not supported")

TypeError: index type not supported
```

[image]

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block or include synthetic data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Also the error does not correspond to any of the code in the example. Please provide a [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to convert the integer dates into yyyy-mm-dd format in the DF.
ltyc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc["Date"], format='%m').apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020))

Then, i converted the DF (ltyc) into a series like this:
ltycs = pd.Series(ltyc['LT Mean'].values, index=ltyc['Date'])#convert to Series since the other plots are in series format

ltycs.plot(label='LT Mean',ax=ax,color='k')